# Heroku commands with inline user / password

Tags: heroku

I'm searching for a 1 line command to log into my heroku account and execute an action.

Example:

heroku apps - Will ask me for my user name and password everytime

I'm looking for something like

heroku -email myuser@gmail.com -password secret apps

So that I can execute everything inline.

Does support for this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you authenticate and log in using the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) your credentials will last for several hours or even days. Could you authenticate before or as part of running your script and then use that? Then you'll be able to run commands with the one-liner of `heroku run {your_command_line_here}`.